# split url and replace

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my URL:

/shop/rest/model/atg/commerce/catalog/ProductCatalogActor/getHardwareFamilySkus?skuId=sku1431389

I need to break url in two diffrent parts show below

abc=>/shop/rest/model/atg/commerce/catalog/ProductCatalogActor/

pqr=>getHardwareFamilySkus?skuId=sku1431389

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to use [String.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with some capturing groups, like this:

```js
const url = "/shop/rest/model/atg/commerce/catalog/ProductCatalogActor/getHardwareFamilySkus?skuId=sku1431389";

const customSplit = (url) =>
{
    let matches = url.match(/^(\/.*\/)(.*)$/);
    return [matches[1], matches[2]];
}

let [abc, pqr] = customSplit(url);

console.log("abc => " + abc);
console.log("pqr => " + pqr);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```